# Button not doing anything

Tags: java, android, xml, button

No error message in Android studio. 'pick image button' does not respond when clicking on it.

I have looked at similar questions but none are specific to my issue, and did not help

xml file:

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/noprofileimg"
        android:id="@+id/profilepic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pick_image_button"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:text="Pick Image"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/Gray"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
```

Activity file,

```
  public class uploadprofileimg extends ActionBarActivity{


private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

    Button pickImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_image_button);
    pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });
}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery =
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my logcat :

```
07-25 11:51:36.776 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]] 07-25 11:51:36.776 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null 07-25 11:51:37.080 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez D/ViewRootImpl@435aa35[ProfileActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer
```

Comment: Please add your logcat.

Comment: @Akriti 07-25 11:51:36.776 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
07-25 11:51:36.776 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
07-25 11:51:37.080 28107-28107/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez D/ViewRootImpl@435aa35[ProfileActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Answer (score 5):

Remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from Button tag in xml.

Comment: Yes, remove that... onClickListener is already done by (java) code!

Answer (score 1):

You had both onclicklistener and onclick attribute for same activity. You can simply remove onclick or just change "onclick" to opengallery to which you have named the method

Answer (score 0):

you have used `pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` in your java code, so you should remove the on click attribute from xml file because by using `android:onClick="onClick"` you directly call a method from your java code in your java there is no user defined function named as onclick.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO has this great feature for making the code look different within the text so that it becomes more readable. Basically you can surround the code portion of your text with three ` characters from the begin and the end. Then it looks like this ```pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ```. The same is for  ```android:onClick="onClick" ```. Good luck and keep those answers coming!